# How can i pass the values i receive from SignalR to my array in Angular?

Tags: .net, angular, frameworks, signalr

i'm using SignalR with net framework and want to implement with Angular 8. I tryed to use the simple chat example on .net framework mvc but i'm having problems with broadcastMessage.

In C#

```
public class Chathub : Hub
    {
        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

In Angular component i created an array so i could push messages to this array and show in realtime on my page, this is how i made

HTML

```
<div>
    <div  *ngFor="let item of mensagens">
      {{item.nome}}: {{item.mensagem}}
    </div>
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  chat:any;
  mensagens: {
    nome: string, mensagem: string
  }[];

  constructor() {
    this.chat = $.connection.chathub;
    this.chat.connection.url = 'http://localhost:61708/signalr';
    this.chat.client.broadcastMessage = function(name: string, message: string)
    {
      this.mensagens.push({nome: name, mensagem: message});
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      console.log('conected');
    });
  }
```

The problem is that in the broadcastMessage function, when i try to access "this.mensagens" ins undefined. I can't access mensagens from that function. How can i pass the values i receive from the broadcastMessage to my array? Thank you.

Comment: `this` is in a different scope, you can try converting that `function` into `=>` function or create a `self` variable to hold `this` value then you do `self.mensagens...`

Comment: Hi, it worked when i change to Arrow function, i add into do array but it doesnt show on the screen. It's add to the array but dont appear on the page instantly, only after i press a button or do something. Do you know what this might be?